# PHP GET Variable till session running

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I've designed my project as this structure `login.php (to login)` `->` `index.php (to select year) -> dashboard.php (project started)`. After login is authenticated, index page is started to select year. And this selected year id is passed to dashboard with javascript.

**Index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#year').change(function() {
    window.location.assign('dashboard.php?id=' + $(this).val());
});
    </script>
```

In dashboard I assign this id as session variable

**dashboard.php**

```
   $_SESSION['year_id'] = $_GET['id'];
```

And in every pages I have used `$_SESSION['year_id']`. It works fine. But problem starts from revisiting dashboard page because `$_GET['id']` becomes undefined index. And it is not best way to select year again and again. Now I want to store get variable till session running.

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['id'])) $_SESSION['year_id']=$_GET['id'];` instead of `$_SESSION['year_id'] = $_GET['id'];`?

Comment: Sometimes my mind just goes blank. Thanks @Syscall for pointing out.